# Roman numerals below the note in violin

Tags: notation, violin, fingering, beginner

I thought the number over the note was the string number for violin. But what are the roman numerals below the score?

How do I finger this score in violin? Could you number on the score please...
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence of Roman numerals below the score is an *alternative* assignment of notes to strings, i.e. you can't follow both at the same time. (The visual hint is that alternatives are often printed in an italic font.)

Comment: I still think it's confusing.  In both cases you start on the G string in 4th position.   It seems like my choices for the start of the second measure are to shift way up on the D string (as shown on bottom), or stay in 4th position on the A string, but the "II" isn't shown until halfway through the measure.

Comment: To clarify, these two fingering options work independently; you would pick one and stick with it. And they're only providing the roman numerals to clarify when needed (showing that, in m 2, the "1" above the G is not 2nd position on E string). Both versions assume that you stay in a given position until told to shift.

Answer (score 2):

The digits (Arabic numerals) above the notes are referring to the fingers you are supposed to use and the roman numerals below the notes are referring to the string you are supposed to play the notes on.

I is the E string
II is the A string
III is the D string
IV is the G string